# Angular 2 import custom component NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm attempting to import a newly created component which is in the same root directory as the app.ts.

```
/
-app.js
-mock_feed_service.js
```

In `app.ts`:

```
import { mock_item_feed } from 'mock_feed_service';
```

Error message:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:63342/mock_feed_service(…)
```

The issue seems to be that the mock_feed_service call is missing the .js extension so the browser can't find it.

```html
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            },
        },
    });
    System.import('app.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I have attempted to add: `"defaultJSExtensions": true`,

Which appears to fix the NOT FOUND issue for this module, but then breaks all my other imports (rxjs/angular2 etc).

e.g.

```
system.src.js:1085 GET http://rxjs/Rx.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your SystemJS configuration, you need to put your TypeScript files under an `app` folder. Otherwise the configuration specified in the `packages` block (`app` entry) won't apply and the `js` extension won't be appended to module names to find out corresponding JS files.

And import your component this way:

```
import { mock_item_feed } from './mock_feed_service';
```

Also update the way you import the `app` module:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
    }
  });
  System.import('app/app') // <-----------
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```